# CFMessagePortSendRequest timeout confusion

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I am using CFMessagePortSendRequest to send a message. At times I get a kCFMessagePortSendTimeout. Does anyone understand the mechanics behind why such a timeout occurs? The apple docs are a bit, um, sparse. The message port is a remote message port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what little information you provided, my best guess is that your CFTimeInterval sendTimeout and CFTimeInterval rcvTimeout values are too small.  Try something like sendTimeout = rcvTimeout = 30;